# Ajax + Json + PHP $_POST don't return values

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get values from my `register()` function. I have used `var_dump($_POST['nick']);` in **ajax/register.php**, but it shows `null`

```html
<section id=signup>
  <label>Nick:</label> 
  <input id=nick maxlength=20><br>

  <label>Email:</label> 
  <input id=email maxlength=40><br>

  <label>Hasło:</label> 
  <input id=pass  maxlength=20 type=password><br>

  <label>Potwierdź hasło:</label> 
  <input id=pass2  maxlength=20 type=password><br>

  <button onclick="register()">Załóż konto</button>
</section>
```

```js
function register() {
  if ($('#pass').val() != $('#pass2').val()) 
    myAlert('Niepoprawne hasło'); 
  else
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      url: "/ajax/register.php",
      data: { 
        n: $('#nick').val(), 
        e: $('#email').val(), 
        p: sha1(SALT + $('#pass').val()) 
      },
      headers: { 
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      }
    }).done(function(d) {
      if (d.e != 'ok') 
        myAlert(d.e);      
      else
        window.location.href = "/";
    });
}
```

Comment: I do hope you are not hashing the password in javascript and expecting that to be secure. The only secure way to communincate anything from browser to server is to use a HTTPS connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing value of `nick` in `n` so you have to get value from `n`

In **ajax/register.php** do

```
var_dump($_POST['n']);
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't any data named "`nick`":

```
data: { n: $('#nick').val(), e:$('#email').val(), p:sha1(SALT+$('#pass').val()) }
```

In `$_POST`, you got `n`, `e` and `p` only.

Use  `var_dump($_POST['n'])` in **ajax/register.php**, to get your `#nick` element value.

Answer (score 3):

You are telling the AJAX call you are going to get JSON back from the PHP, but you are not sending JSON back from the PHP when you use `var_dump($_POST['nick']);` Also you are passing the value on a key of `n:` and not `nick`

So in PHP replace this

```
var_dump($_POST['nick']);
```

with

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

This will return all the `$_POST` array back to the javascript

And in the javascript replace

```
.done(function(d) {
  if (d.e != 'ok') 
    myAlert(d.e);      
  else
    window.location.href = "/";
```

with

```
.done(function(d) {
    // I dont think you set e to 'ok' anywhere
  //if (d.e != 'ok') 
    myAlert(d.e);
    myAlert(d.n);
    myAlert(d.p);
}
```